# Фильтрация записей в вордпресс

Tags: wordpress, post

Предположим у меня есть десять записей в вордпресс. Я хочу опубликовать только пять из них с помощью цикла с использованием have_posts(). Как это сделать ?

Comment: Используйте wp_query для запроса https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query

Answer (score 1):

Далеко ходить не надо, набрал в гугле have_posts и нашёл подходящий ответ на сайте у Миши Рудрастых

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'category_name'  =>  'my-cat',
    'posts_per_page' =>  5,
) );
     
if( $query->have_posts() ) { 
    while( $query->have_posts() ) { 
        get_template_part( '/template-parts/tipa-post' );
    }
} 
wp_reset_postdata();
```